# Record Level security

Tags: axapta

I have a Empltable where I assigned Record Level security through  Administration => RecordLevelSecurity

But the problem is that all the employees are in same group. When they open the form they should see their data only, not the other employees data?

This specification is done based on curUserId(). In the query we get emplId's but the user info is in "user" in Administration module.

I intend not to write the code. How can I achieve this functionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SysQueryRangeUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc618616%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) class method `currentEmployeeId` may come to rescue.

Also see [Shekhar Diptiman's space](http://shekhardiptiman.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/dynamics-ax2009-%E2%80%93-useful-utility-%E2%80%9Csysqueryrangeutil%E2%80%9D/).

Comment: @Vivek ::Hi Jan B. Kjeldsen , I personally appreciate your help. You have answered my two questions very accurately. I want to know how are you getting the appropriate blogs for the questions which you have been asked.I want a few tips from you that how I can be a good consultant in Dynamics Ax . My mail Id is chirumammilavivek@gmail.com. You can contact me any time when you are free. Thank you once again.

Comment: Working 14 years with AX kinda helps. In this case I could remember that a range util class existed, but I could not remember the exact name. Then I did what everybody else do, I googled it and found the blog as well. I do keep a long blog list in Google reader, most will be found here: http://www.axaptapedia.com/Axapta_Communities.